# Is $(f \circ g)(x) = g(f(x))$ Common in Group Theory?

Tags: group-theory, notation

In the text [Group Theory and the Rubik’s Cube](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~jjchen/docs/Group%20Theory%20and%20the%20Rubik's%20Cube.pdf) by Janet Chen, definition 1.11. on page $4$ says

> If $f:S_1 \to S_2$ and $g:S_2 \to S_3$, then we can define a new function $f\circ g: S_1 \to S_3$ as $(f \circ g)(x) = g(f(x))$

As far as I am aware, the order is reversed compared to what I've encountered before. How common is this in group theory, or perhaps in all of mathematics?

Comment: This is why in group theory, exponential notation is quite common. You would denote $f(x)$ by $x^f$ and then you have $x^{f\circ g}=(x^f)^g$ and there is no problem. Some authors even write this as $x(f\circ g) = (xf)g$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not uncommon, though perhaps not common. I first learned abstract algebra through Herstein's book, which uses reversed-order composition, and later through Dummit and Foote's book, which uses ordinary order composition.

I opened my copy of Herstein to say what he says about this. I copy a relevant passage.

> Let $\sigma$ be a mapping from $S$ to $T$; we often denote this by writing $\sigma: S \to T$. If $t$ is the image of $s$ under $\sigma$ we shall sometimes write this as $\sigma:s \to t$; more often, we shall represent this fact by $t = s\sigma$. Note that we write the mapping $\sigma$ on the *right*. There is no overall consistency in this usage; many people would write it as $t = \sigma(s)$. Algebraists often write mappings on the right; other mathematicians write them on the left. In fact, we shall not be absolutely consistent in this ourselves; when we shall want to emphasize the functional nature of $\sigma$ we may very well write $t = \sigma(s)$.

Later, with composition, he writes

> We have a mapping $\sigma$ from $S$ to $T$ and another mapping $\tau$ from $T$ to $U$. Can we compound these mappings to produce a mapping from $S$ to $U$? ... Note that the order of events reads from left to right; $\sigma \circ \tau$ reads: first perform $\sigma$ and then follow it up with $\tau$. Here too the left-right business is not a uniform one.

Answer (score 4):

It's not that common, but it's certainly done in more than one text, especially when it comes to talking about multiplication of permutations in the symmetric group.

Note that the annoying fact that $f \circ g$ means "do g, then f" is really an artifact of the decision to write "$f$ evaluated at $x$" as $f(x)$. If instead we wrote it as $(x)f$, then function composition notation would make sense. Obviously it is too late to change this.

Since we choose to write function evaluation as $f(x)$, either $f \circ g$ has to mean the functions are performed in the reverse order from what is written (standard usage) or it has to reverse symbolically when we write what it means (the usage in your source and a few others).

Answer (score 2):

This is irregular in all the current maths literature that I know. We are usually taught to read the little circle as the verb "follows". But it need not be an error if the author is carefully consistent; just confusing.

Comment: Thank you, I added my own answer, because I sadly completely missed that the author comments on this just below the definition. Not sure what that says about my attention, since I read the text twice already.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering myself, because I missed the comment just below this definition which makes this quite clear:

> "We are using this convention because it
>   matches the convention usually used for the Rubik’s cube."

Thus, unless someone adds interesting details, the answer is:

**No**, it is not common. However, it (supposedly) is common in Rubik's cube notation.

Comment: Sigh...The lacking of a true *common* convention really makes me sad.

Comment: I have seen books that compose maps by writing them in the order $fg,$ especially in the context of permutations. But this is the first time that I see the $\circ$ symbol used for that.